# how would you take the white pixels generated by a mask and put them into a list

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have a picture of a street, (the street has small variations of color) and with some help I was able to crop part of the street for a sample of the color I then took the color and calculated the mean and stdv and created the lower and upper boundry for a mask. 
I took the mask output and ran `closing = cv2.morphologyEx(output, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)`

I would like to take all the white pixels that are in closing and create a list of their x,y coordinates.
then I would like to take the x,y coordinates and create another list of there b,g,r values.

so then I can run it back through

```
blue=cropimg[:,:,0]; green=cropimg[:,:,1]; red=cropimg[:,:,2];
```

See image, showing: original, mask, closing, cropped areas:

[image: original, mask, closing, cropped areas]

Comment: Something like [`findNonZero`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaed7df59a3539b4cc0fe5c9c8d7586190)? NB: It exists even in the 2.4 branch, although for some reason documentation doesn't seem to mention it. Or you could go with [`numpy.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero).

Comment: Another option would be [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Something like `blue_vals = blue[np.where(mask > 0)]`...

Comment: @DanMašek, the one-argument form of `where` is identical to `nonzero`, so that's really just the same option. Also, `blue[mask > 0]` is a shorter way of spelling that

Comment: I'm trying to use your suggestion of blueval = blue[mask>0]

I'm getting a type error saying that only integer arrays with 1 element can be added to an index. 

a solution for that error suggested that you turn blue[] in the an np.array[]

but then that gave me an index error "index 992 is out of bounds of axis.."

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're simply looking for:

```
rgb = cropimg[mask,:]  # or mask > 0, if mask is not a boolean array
```

which will return an `Nx3` array of the pixels under the mask

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the lists you asked, you can do it like:

```
coords, colors = [], []
for y in range(closing.shape[0]):
    for x in range(closing.shape[1]):
        if np.all(closing[y, x] > 0):
            coords.append((y, x))
            colors.append(original[y, x])
```

Thus you get a list with the white coordinates and the BGR values in those coordinates in the original image.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm getting a value error at "if closing[y, x] == (0, 0, 0):"
value error:  "the truth value of an array with more then one element is ambiguous try a.all() or a.any()

Answer (score 1):

ebeneditos, I found that this works, but for large images it takes too much time.

```
 coords, colors = [], []
    for y in range(closing.shape[0]):
        for x in range(closing.shape[1]):
            if np.all(closing[y, x] > 0):
                coords.append((y, x))
                colors.append(img[y, x])
```

Comment: I know, it is not the optimal way, maybe you should look for another approach. I edited my answer btw!